How to generate sharp anime style shadows in substance painter?
I'm trying to achieve a 2d/hand painted look for my 3d models and i wanted to know if there is a faster way to have sharp anime style shadows on my models instead of just painting it manually.
I'm currently using substance painter but any other way to achieve this result in substance designer or other softwares would be helpful too.
Thanks for your help.

Raytracing in your 3d app.

The shadow depends on the render engine, not neccesary the texture.
Take a look at Blender and this special Fork of it:
https://www.dillongoostudios.com/gooengine
Or with different render settings on the main Blender:
https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=blender+anime+render+engine
